# Boy goes insane during space travel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the name of a short story I read about 25 years ago or so. I'd also like to know of any collections it appeared in.

The details I recall involve a family who are embarking on a hyperspace journey. To undertake this journey you have to be put to sleep. One of the children pretends to be asleep, and when the jump is complete the child has gone insane. From the child's point of view the jump lasted for an eternity while in reality it was only a few seconds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like Stephen King's The Jaunt.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jaunt):

> The father then reveals the nature of why any conscious being goes insane or dies after being Jaunted: while physically the process occurs nearly instantaneously (the condemned man traveled two miles between two portals in 0.000000000067 seconds), to a conscious mind it lasts an eternity

and

> When the father wakes, he finds that his inquisitive son held his breath while being administered the general anesthesia in order to experience the Jaunt while conscious, and has been rendered completely insane.

Comment: I remember this story. A convict went in first and said something along the same lines; "It's eternity in there." I believe it was in the anthology 'Nightmares and Dreamscapes', but I can't recall for sure.

Comment: The linked Wiki page says it was in Skeleton Crew. It's a great story!

Comment: In my edit, I forgot to include the anthology in which it was published--as Rob and Wikipedia indicate *Skeleton Crew* (It was first published in *The Twilight Zone Magazine*.) This should be included in the answer itself (perhaps with an [amazon link](http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0451168615), so SE might get some money)--re-editing myself does not seem right.